# How can l uninstall PyTorch with Anaconda?

Tags: python, ubuntu, anaconda, pytorch

I installed PyTorch with:

```
conda install pytorch torchvision cuda80 -c soumith
```

How do I uninstall and remove all PyTorch dependencies?

Answer (score 56):

From the [anaconda docs](https://conda.io/docs/commands/conda-uninstall.html), you can uninstall with `conda uninstall`

Try

```
conda uninstall pytorch torchvision cuda80 -c soumith
```

Alternatively, the [pytorch docs](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/blob/master/CONTRIBUTING.md) suggest

```
conda uninstall pytorch
pip uninstall torch
pip uninstall torch # run this command twice
```

Comment: This does not remove all the files.

Comment: Hey @Schütze Could you please elaborate a bit more on this issue.

Comment: I also uninstalled pytorch like this, but then I got the error "ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found". The solution to that again was https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44537131/numpy-library-importerror-dll-load-failed-the-specified-procedure-could-not-be
and there the answer of @User1024, by adding a Path variable.

p.s.: I have not done anything else than uninstalling pytorch, that is why I think this is a relevant post to this topic, though it does not directly answer the question.

Answer (score 15):

Here's the correct set of commands according to [CONTRIBUTING.md](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/blob/master/CONTRIBUTING.md#developing-locally-with-pytorch) from the pytorch github repo:

---

Uninstall all existing pytorch installs

```
conda uninstall pytorch
pip uninstall torch
pip uninstall torch # run this command twice
```

Comment: I had to use pip uninstall since I had installed a Wheel with pip. The uninstall works, but it also threw an error: `  Successfully uninstalled torch-1.5.1+cu92
ERROR: Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Admin\anaconda3\envs\ml\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\cli\base_command.py", line 216, in _main
    status = self.run(options, args)` ... `PermissionError: [WinError 5] Zugriff verweigert: 'C:\\Users\\Admin\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-uninstall-dtsa8at_\\lib\\c10.dll'` I guess this error will not pop up in Admin mode, or the dll just should not be deleted.

Answer (score 9):

You can also use

```
conda remove torch torchvision
```

Please note that this will **remove** the specified packages (here: *torch and torchvision*) and any other package which depends on *torch and torchvision*, if there're any.

P.S. `conda uninstall` is an alias to `conda remove`.

Answer (score 4):

Perhaps @Schütze meant with "This does not remove all the files." that there are still files in the Anaconda\pkgs folder.

Mind that you can remove the tar.b2 and the folder of the now unused packages in Anaconda\pkgs. I uninstalled pytorch cuda version (because my display driver does not support cuda) and there were huge files there:

- pytorch-1.5.0-py3.7_cuda102_cudnn7_0.tar.bz2
- pytorch-1.5.0-py3.7_cuda102_cudnn7_0
- cudatoolkit-10.2.89-h74a9793_1.conda
- cudatoolkit-10.2.89-h74a9793_1

This makes 3 GB altogether! Either do this manually, or with a command:

to delete all unneeded packages:

```
    conda clean --yes --packages --dry-run
```

to delete all unneeded tar.bz2 / conda

```
    conda clean --yes --tarballs --dry-run
```

to delete all together

```
    conda clean --yes --all --dry-run
```

First use parameter --dry-run to see what will happen. Afterwards, run without --dry-run.
This has cleaned about 3.5 GB of the used 7 GB disk space that was used by Anaconda\pkgs.

References:
[How to uninstall all unused packages in a conda virtual environment?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36308531/how-to-uninstall-all-unused-packages-in-a-conda-virtual-environment#comment60251236_36308531) and
[Anaconda Python: Delete .tar.gz in pkgs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44708392/anaconda-python-delete-tar-gz-in-pkgs)

Answer (score 0):

You can safely delete the pytorch installation using the following conda command:

```
conda uninstall pytorch-cpu torchvision-cpu pytorch
```

Answer (score -1):

I recently found a good tool!

```
pip install pip-autoremove
```

This tool can delete all the tools you need to delete. For example, if you need to delete the torch, then it can delete torchvision as well!

```
Usage: pip-autoremove [OPTION]... [NAME]...

Options:
  --version     show program's version number and exit
  -h, --help    show this help message and exit
  -l, --list    list unused dependencies, but don't uninstall them.
  -L, --leaves  list leaves (packages which are not used by any others).
  -y, --yes     don't ask for confirmation of uninstall deletions.
```