# issue while import pytorch in Anaconda

Tags: pytorch

(test_pytorch) C:\Users\kuntal chowdhury>python
Python 3.8.3 (default, May 19 2020, 06:50:17) [MSC v.1916 64 bit (AMD64)] :: Anaconda, Inc. on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.

> > > import torch
> > >       Traceback (most recent call last):
> > >         File "", line 1, in 
> > >         File "C:\Users\kuntal chowdhury\Anaconda3\envs\test_pytorch\lib\site-packages\torch__init__.py", line 81, in 
> > >           ctypes.CDLL(dll)
> > >         File "C:\Users\kuntal chowdhury\Anaconda3\envs\test_pytorch\lib\ctypes__init__.py", line 373, in **init**
> > >           self._handle = _dlopen(self._name, mode)
> > >       FileNotFoundError: Could not find module 'C:\Users\kuntal chowdhury\Anaconda3\envs\test_pytorch\lib\site-packages\torch\lib\caffe2_nvrtc.dll' (or one of its dependencies). Try using the full path with constructor syntax.

Answer (score 0):

See [this answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61488902/cannot-import-pytorch-winerror-126-the-specified-module-could-not-be-found)

TL;DR, I suspect you are trying to run torch from an environment that does not have CUDA installed.  Thus, you must install the cpu version of torch:

```
conda install pytorch torchvision cpuonly -c pytorch
```