# Cannot Uninstall Pytorch

Tags: macos, pip, pytorch, conda

I've installed pytorch 0.4.1 with both pip and conda in an effort to get a specific package working. Somehow version 1.5.0 is installed somewhere on my filesystem and despite my best efforts (following [all these instructions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43664444/how-can-l-uninstall-pytorch)) I cannot find and uninstall this version.
Running `python3.6 -c "import torch; print(torch.__version__)"` results in `1.5.0` no matter how many uninstalls I attempt.
I was using some virtual environments to help in my development, using `venv`.
I am running macOS 10.15.4, Intel Core i9 8-core, 32 GB 2667 DDR4, AMD Radeon Pro 5500M 8 GB.

Comment: How about you install to a specific location and update the bashrc file to point to the installation location?

Comment: @WasiAhmad I was able to locate and delete the version that was installed. See my answer for details.

Comment: You installed the package inside a Conda environment?

Comment: @AMC Nope, my environments were made using `venv`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to locate all installs of torch using `sudo find . -name "*torch*"`.

My version, which I ended up deleting 'by hand', was located at `/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/torch`.

Hopefully this can help someone else.