# Anaconda Python: Delete .tar.gz in pkgs

Tags: python, anaconda, package

Would it be a problem to delete *.tar.gz files in `C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\conda\pkgs`? I also see subdirectories of Python of the same Python package, but in different versions (e.g., `pandas-0.19.2-np111py27_1`, `pandas-0.19.2-np111py35_1`, `pandas-0.20.1-np112py27_0`, `pandas-0.20.1-np112py35_0`, `pandas-0.20.1-np112py36_0`, `pandas-0.20.2-np112py27_0`, `pandas-0.20.2-np112py36_0`, `pandas-0.20.2-np113py36_0`). I currently have two environments (Python 2.7 and 3.6), so I don't want to be wasting storage with different versions of the same package, or for Python versions I'm not currently using (I'm talking GB here!). Is there a proper way of deleting those files/directories (and is there a problem in doing that)?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You can run `conda clean --tarballs` in your terminal.

#### Reference:

https://conda.io/docs/commands/conda-clean.html

Comment: Nice, thanks! That got rid of the tarballs. I'm still left with the apparently redundant directories...

Comment: `conda clean --all` cleans everything, period.