# The python version update in anaconda took up too much disk。

Tags: python, anaconda

I updated the built-in python version in anaconda.

`conda update python`

However, the disk space was significantly reduced by about 1GB to 2GB after completion. It doesn't look like updating the python version but adding a new one. Now the Anaconda folder is taking up a lot of disk space. As a python novice, how do I free my disk?

Comment: [Possible duplicate] Please have a look here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36308531/how-to-uninstall-all-unused-packages-in-a-conda-virtual-environment

Comment: Thanks, I finished it with "conda clean -p".

Comment: If you're tight on disk space, then why not use [MiniConda](https://docs.conda.io/en/latest/miniconda.html) and only install what you need?